# Ruby string include? two or more statements

Tags: ruby

Im programming beginner and started with ruby. Now i try to search through documents and see if there is an patient included. I realized this task with this code:

```
@patients.each do |patient|
   if document.include? patient.nachnahme || document.include? patient.vorname
   arr << a 
  end
end
```

But somehow i get the error:

```
syntax error, unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting keyword_then or ';' or '\n'
if document.include? patient.nachnahme || document.include? patient.vorname
```

SO what did i wrong? And how can i define that my ruby code only runs when:

```
document.include? patient.nachnahme || document.include? patient.vorname
```

both statements are true?

Comment: Probably a precedence issue. Try: `if (document.include? patient.nachnahme) || (document.include? patient.vorname)`.

Comment: Works great!What happens when document.include?(patient.nachnahme) || document.include?(patient.vorname) both statements are wrong?

Comment: Then the `if` expression will be false and the enclosed statements (following the `if` before the closing `end`) will not be executed

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What you need to do is put `()` around your `include?` calls.

```
document.include?(patient.nachnahme) || document.include?(patient.vorname)
```

Ruby tends to get a little confused when you do a double conditional which also has method calls without `()` since technically you could be calling:

```
# Not what you are intending
document.include?(patient.nachnahme || document.include? patient.vorname)
```

Comment: Works great!What happens when document.include?(patient.nachnahme) || document.include?(patient.vorname) both statements are wrong?

Comment: @EmSta Then the `if` expression will be false and the enclosed statements (following the `if` before the closing `end`) will not be executed

Comment: You can also use the very weak binding `or`.

Comment: It has nothing to do with confusion but with [operator precedence](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Ruby_Operator_Precedence#Operator_Precedence_Table) ;-)

Comment: It is not good practice to use `||` and `&&` in control-flow operations..@tadman is wright...

Comment: @padde I have a bad habit of anthropomorphizing the Ruby interpreter. =)

Comment: Don't lose that habit :)

Comment: "`It is not good practice to use || and && in control-flow operations`"? Huh? Not! It's preferable to use them. The problem the OP ran into is operator precedence, which @Tadman points out could have been handled alternatively using `or`, but `and` and `or` are not preferable over the normal boolean operators. Using `or` and `and` indiscriminately can lead to their own precedence problems, so it's important to KNOW what you're doing, and to force precedence using parenthesis whenever it could be unclear. The OP could have used parens to bind the parameters to the methods and all would be OK.

Comment: @theTinMan I linked too a great author blog also,just to handle you like comments.."Huh?"... Sorry I can't agree with you.. OP's solution can be fixed using `()`, its OK that's a fix only... But not a best practice to use for control flow techniques...

Comment: You're welcome to disagree. I'm basing this on a lot of experience, plus [The Ruby Style Guide](https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide) which says: `The and and or keywords are banned. It's just not worth it. Always use && and || instead.` Also `Use parentheses around the arguments of all other method invocations.`

Comment: I'm with @Priti on this one. Use strong binding operators like `||` within expressions or arguments and loose binding operators like `or` for control flow. There's a hundred style guides out there, some of which ban things, and others which require them. To each their own.

Comment: @theTinMan I heavily obeyed *Avdi*.. and I very often to clear my concept by him through email.. So I cant't over rule his statement. *Go as you like*...

Answer (score 3):

write it as

```
if document.include? patient.nachnahme or document.include? patient.vorname
```

Tried to reproduce the issue here:

```
"aaa".include? "a" or "bb".inlcude? "v"
# => true
"aaa".include? "a" || "bb".inlcude? "v"
# ~> -:2: syntax error, unexpected tSTRING_BEG, expecting ')'
# ~> ...include? "a" || "bb".inlcude? "v");$stderr.puts("!XMP1374693...
# ~> ...
```

**Note**

> Always consider to use **and** and **or** operators for *control flow* operations.[**using-and-and-or-in-ruby**](http://devblog.avdi.org/2010/08/02/using-and-and-or-in-ruby/)